# PhpStorm FTP 425 Unable to build data connection: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: sockets, ftp, phpstorm, time-wait

PhpStorm FTP upload failed.

```
[17-1-16 下午5:17] Failed to transfer file '/a': cant open output connection for file "ftp://192.168.1.229:21/a". Reason: "425 Unable to build data connection: Cannot assign requested address".
[17-1-16 下午5:17] Upload to server completed in less than a minute: 108 files transferred, 3 items failed (541.1 Kb/s)
```

My PhpStorm running on deepin system (Linux)

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10000     65000
```

I tried to change the number of ports, but still failed to upload.
Who can help me ?

Comment: Can you connect to the address manually?

Comment: Yes,FTP server is running normally.

Comment: 1) Try enabling extra logging https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs) and see what `idea.log` will have to say about it (Help | Show Log in XXX). But TBH I do not expect you to find any answer there -- I guess it's more of a way how actual Deployment works in PhpStorm.... 2) Just an idea -- maybe it's somehow related to "Send keep alive message each xxx seconds"? 3) What's your PhpStorm version? Maybe try latest 2016.3.2 if you do not use it already

Comment: @LazyOne  1) Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Cant open output connection for file "ftp://10.13.1.229:2121/Application/Admin/View/default/Index/index.html". Reason: "425 Unable to build data connection: Cannot assign requested address  2) keep alive 30 seconds 3) My phpstorm version is 2016.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in IntelliJ IDEA.

Changing the connection type from **FTP** to **SFTP** helped. I hope it's also possible for you.